# vbscript to read an attribute value in xml and change it depending on what the value is x2

Tags: vbscript, setattribute

I have a vbscript that changes the port value via cmd: cmd /c cscript "C:\Temp\port.vbs" 12

Heres the script:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("FILE.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDocName = "C:\Temp\Config.xml"
xmlDoc.Load(xmlDocName)

Set xmlNode = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//TCPIPLink")
xmlNode.SetAttribute "RemotePort", WScript.Arguments(0)
xmlDoc.Save(xmlDocName)
```

What I've been asked to do is change the "RemotePort" number 10 to 12 and if it set to 13 change to 14
what is the best way to adapt this script?
I have no scripting knowledge so please be nice thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Dim iRemotePort
iRemotePort = WScript.Arguments(0)

Select Case iRemotePort
    Case 10
        iRemotePort = 12
    Case 13
        iRemotePort = 14
    Case Else
        ' Leave it as-is
End Select

xmlNode.SetAttribute "RemotePort", iRemotePort
xmlDoc.Save (xmlDocName)
```